# Confusions in NDK samples

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am a beginner to `Android NDK` with `Android Studio`. While trying to grasp the ideas through tutorials I got my self very confused. Mainly I am confused about the building method of native project.

For example while following [this](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/) tutorial, when I build the project there is no file created inside libs project. Moreover, there is no need of `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` make files also.

However, [second](http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html) tutorial deals with the make file.

Can anyone please explain to me step by step explanation of build steps. I am not sure how hard it is for `Android` team to make a simple tutorial explanation one version of built.

Comment: Please narrow the question down to one specific thing (e.g. one specific build step that you're having trouble understanding). Right now it would be very difficult to answer this question, because we can't possibly know from what you've written what your current level of understanding is (let alone the current level of understanding of every single person that will find this question in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if by the time of this writing (**2016/02/01** - `Android Studio` 2.0 Preview 9) `NDK` is **officially supported** yet, but it's surely been under development. That's the reason of using `Eclipse`+`ADT`+`NDK` in the official guide as you can see in the [Setup](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/setup.html) section. I believe, once the process is done, the documentation will be updated.

You're free to choose which approach to use:

- `Eclipse`+`ADT`+`NDK` or
- `Android Studio` + `Gradle` + `NDK`

With the second approach `Gradle` generates `*.mk` files automatically, although you can use your own files by preventing the auto-generation as per [The new NDK support in Android Studio](http://ph0b.com/new-android-studio-ndk-support/) by [ph0b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094884/ph0b).

Comment: thanks @Onik that actually removes my confusion I hope in future their documentation will become consistent. As even the samples came with ndk-bundle are also compiled for eclipse.